# How to disconnect all handlers from the scroll event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am looking at a giant code base with 30-40 JavaScript includes doing all kinds of stuff, including hooking into events.

I am looking to programmatically disconnect any handlers for the `scroll` event (window or document).  Preferably from the console tab in the <kbd>F12</kbd> tools.

Is it possible in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You probably already found out that you cannot use `removeEventListener`, since you need to know which function is the event handler to detach.

But you could create a wrapper around `addEventListener` so when it gets called, you don't translate that to a call to the real `addEventListener` method.

You would put this `script` element in the `head` section, *before* any of `script` tags that include the libraries:

```
<script>
window.origAddEventListener = window.addEventListener;
window.addEventListener = function (type, f, options) {
    if (type === "scroll") return; // do not add the listener
    window.origAddEventListener(type, f, options);
};
</script>
```

You could do something similar for `document.addEventListener`.

This way you *prevent* event handlers to be registered for the `scroll` event on the `window` (or `document`) element.